# Qualcomm Atheros AR5B125 wireless network adapter replacement

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, adapter

I have an Acer Aspire 7250 laptop with this adapter. Yes, it’s old and slow, but it suits my purpose and everything works. I am running Windows 10. My ISP gives me speeds up to 200 mbps. I currently get about 50 mbps or less. I have a TP-Link AC1350 dual band router. Will replacing this wireless network adapter with an Intel AC-7260 give me noticeably better WiFi speeds or will it not help at all?